# rhythmbox control panel not working

Tags: rhythmbox

facing issue with Rhythmbox control panel. I am unable to pause or play next song from control panel of Rhythmbox music player[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the indicator sound menu to work correctly you need to ensure that the MPRIS plugin is enabled:

[image: pic]

Move you mouse to the top of the screen and choose the Edit menu and its Plugin submenu.  Tick the option shown.

---

If you cannot see the MPRIS D-Bus Interface plugin then it is likely that you do not have the `rhythmbox-plugins` package installed.

In a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

Comment: it seems this plugin is not installed. Could you please guide me how do i install this plugin?

Comment: Sandesh - I've updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: started working after installing plugins